# Is Content Hot Swapping possible in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

It seems like something I should be able to find easily but my google foo is failing me. Does unity support content hot swapping? ie I m using a 3d model, or a texture, if i update on disk, does unity reload automatically while I m in game (not deployed, just debug the game)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is at least for the meshes of 3D models (I use Blender only) and for textures. Scripts will lead to a crash in most cases when an instance is active already.

In a previous version on Unity I have seen issues related to animations. Maybe it works now or under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about model but the texture def reloads. I do it all the time. I'll modify a PNG, and or PSD in Photoshop and the changes will be transparent in the app. Same with sounds, and modifying code as well. Especially  code that's in the update() and FixedUpdate() functions or if a level is reloaded, etc.

If you add a new variable scripts sometimes breaks. Also if you add sounds or modify sounds, the new sound will popup in the editor. Best thing to do is pause it, and then load it in then unpause in the UNITY EDITOR.

The IDE once it detects something new will try and reimport it, whether it is playing, stopped or pause.

Comment: also OnGUI(), too. Left it out.